# Trying to click on 1,000 spans on a web-page using a program. Is this possible?

Tags: html, spring, user-interface, testing, automated-tests

My web-page has a number of icons, each of which is in a different row of a table, which can be identified like so.

There are over 1000 of these.

Essentially, I just want to write a tiny script which will, in my browser, click on each one. This will kick off a download of each file. Unfortunately, there is no better way to do this for various reasons - and it is a once off script.

The icons are differentiated like so :

```
<span class="button" 
      id="docgrid_row_0_download">
</span>

<span class="button" 
      id="docgrid_row_1_download">
</span>
```

Is there any programmatic way of getting my browser to click on each one? Notice the difference between each id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure JavaScript solution using id's to identify the elements.

```
for (i = 0; document.getElementById("docgrid_row_" + i + "_download") != null; i++)
{
    document.getElementById("docgrid_row_" + i + "_download").click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the console, if you have jQuery included on the site do

```
// may need a more specific selector depending on rest of page
$('span.button').each(function () {
    $(this).click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.setTimeout(27,function(){
// do work like parse dom for each id
}
```

[setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)